# Do I need to install Joomla again for subdirectory?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

Till now I was comfortable in installing and using Joomla in single server directory say “mywebsite”. Now my requirement is to have subdirectory say “mywebsite/exam” which will have its own index file. Do I need to install Joomla for sub directory too??? Or else is there any way so need not to install Joomla in subdirectory and have same UI as the parent directory.

Comment: You can install a new Joomla! in your new directory. But, remember about the database of both should be different. Create a new database for new site and setup it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you create a menu item called exam and you have SEF URLs turned on it should automatically create that "subdirectory". Only it will be a virtual subdirectory.

Then you could simply assign all your modules to that menu item. Unless you are wanting to have different users for each site but I don't think that would be necessary in this case.